# How to get last week sunday date using jquery

Tags: jquery, date, datetime

I am trying to get last week sunday date with "mm-dd-yyyy" format using jquery. Is there an easy solution out there for this?

Comment: Take a look at momentJs

Answer (score 2):

get latest sunday with one sentence:

```
var latestSunday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - new Date().getDay()));
```

get last sunday with one sentence:

```
var lastSunday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - (new Date().getDay()==0?7:new Date().getDay())));
```

it seems verbose, you can divide the answer as you wish. then, you can use other date format plugins to format the date, like jQuery dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string then subtract the day value to get the previous sunday

```js
var string = '01-31-2015';
var date = new Date(string);
date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay())
snippet.log(date)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

If the simple parsing of date is not working then

```js
var string = '01-31-2015';
var parts = string.split('-'),
  date = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());

snippet.log(date)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week

var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();

firstday
"Sun, 18 OCT 2015 12:25:40 GMT"
```